# Jupyter Extension offsets all timestamps by timezone where server is running

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Jupyter Service is running on IST timezone. All timestamp fields are offset by the timezone. How to configure Jupyter to ignore timezone?